# Estimate uncertainty of window average

Tags: uncertainty, measurement

I have some random process $y(t)$ that represent an unknown signal combined with some random high frequency positive feedback noise, that is noise amplitude grows with the value of the signal.

I think I can model this with $$y(t) = (1 + \sin(\omega t))\cdot(1 + \alpha \sin(K\omega t + \varphi) )$$
where $omega$ and $\alpha$ are parameters and $\varphi$ gives an appropriately scaled Gaussian random phase shift.
[image: plot of the signal polluted with high frequency positive feedback noise]

Suppose now to get an estimate of the unknown signal I resample it on a set of contiguous intervals $\tau_1,\ldots, \tau_n$ as

$$ \langle y \rangle (i) = \frac{1}{|\tau_i|}\int_{\tau_i} y(t)dt$$

In my understanding uncertainty $u(\langle y \rangle (i))$ is a number $u$ such that roughly 70% of sampled values of $y(t)$ on $\tau_i$ would lie in the range $$[\langle y \rangle (i) - u, \langle y \rangle (i) + u].$$

To estimate the uncertainty $u(\langle y \rangle (i))$ my first idea would be to compute the standard deviation

$$ u(\langle y \rangle (i)) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{|\tau_i|}\int_{\tau_i} (y(t) - \langle y \rangle (i))^2 dt}.$$

However this seems to overestimate the uncertainty

[image: resampled signal with uncertainty]

This seems to be an estimation of the uncertainty of $y(t)$ itself not the resampled and averaged signal.

My intuition suggests that if $y(t)$ were sampled at a certain rate so that each interval $\tau_i$ would contain roughly $n$ samples then $\langle y\rangle (i)$ would have $n$ degrees of freedom therefore

$$ \langle y \rangle (i) = \frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\Sigma_{t_j \in \tau_i} y(t_j)$$

and

**Formula 1:**
$$ u(\langle y \rangle (i)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\displaystyle\Sigma_{t_j \in \tau_i} (y(t_j) - \langle y \rangle (i))^2}$$

[image: uncertainty calculated depending on the number of degrees of freedom]

So that the higher the sampling rate, the lower would the uncertainty be.

While in the former case:

**Formula 2:**
$$ u(\langle y \rangle (i)) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\Sigma_{t_j \in \tau_i} (y(t_j) - \langle y \rangle (i))^2}.$$

the uncertainty would not depend on the sampling rate.

Which uncertainty estimation is correct, Formula 1, Formula 2, or neither?